# How to set scale for a brush in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a brush in the React app. So I imported brushX function from the d3-brush module and do the following:

```
import  {brushX}  from 'd3-brush';

let brush = brushX()
 .x(this.x)
 .extent([initWindow.start, initWindow.end])
 .on("brush", this.display);
```

I got the error - .x() is not a function.
[image]

So how I can set scale to the brash?

Following part of the code works fine in non React app (d3js was downloaded from the mdn):

```
    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .extent([initWindow.start, initWindow.end])
    .on("brush", display);
```

Comment: Try with this. 

    `let brush = brushX()
     .x((d, i, node)=>{ node[i].x;})
     .extent([initWindow.start, initWindow.end])
     .on("brush", this.display);`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it doesn't  work. I got the same error